# Make spdlog save the file before app crashes

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, qt5, spdlog

I added logging capabilities to my application and it working fine.
However in one particular case it is crashing, and in that case I cannot see the logs.

Looks like my application is crashing before the log file is saved (I guess). Can I force spdlog to save the file?

Comment: I believe the best way is to implement the memory mapped file sink an use it instead of file sink. The reason is when application writes the data to the memory mapped file, the data written is available for read to the kernel/other app right away and you do not have to flush it.

Comment: How can I  implement the memory mapped file sink?

Comment: Added solution. See below

Answer (score 3):

you could call the `logger->flush()` function to manual flush.
or
you could use `my_logger->flush_on(spdlog::level::err)` to set the minimum log level that will trigger automatic flush.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to achieve the goal is to implement the memory mapped file sink and use it instead of file sink. The reason is when application writes the data to the memory mapped file, the data is immediately available to the kernel and other apps so you do not have to flush it.

I do not have an implementation for the memory mapped file sink, but you can start with `boost::ostream` adapter for the `boost::mapped_file` and create `spdlog::ostream_sink_mt`.

**NOTE:** You should take care of the case when the memory mapped file region is fully loaded. In this case you should resize the file and map the next region to the memory.

```cpp
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051067/c-boost-write-memory-mapped-file
// https://spdlog.docsforge.com/v1.x/4.sinks/#available-sinks

#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/ostream_sink.h>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> strArray(2000000);

    bio::mapped_file_params params;
    params.path          = "text.txt";
    params.new_file_size = 65536;
    params.flags         = bio::mapped_file::mapmode::readwrite;

    bio::stream<bio::mapped_file_sink> out(params);
    auto ostream_sink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::ostream_sink_mt> (out);
    auto logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("my_logger", ostream_sink);
    logger->info("Test message");
}
```

Credits:

- [c++ boost write memory mapped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051067/c-boost-write-memory-mapped-file)
- https://spdlog.docsforge.com/v1.x/4.sinks/#available-sinks